# Retrieve log files from EMR nodes after unknown termination failure?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-emr

We have an EMR cluster that failed for an unknown reason.
The last event was `Amazon EMR Cluster ... has terminated with errors with a reason of INSTANCE_FAILURE`

I am currently trying to diagnose it. I would like to retrieve log files from the EMR nodes (Master, Core, Task) but they are all terminated.

Unfortunately we do not configure EMR to push logs to S3.

Is there any way for me to manually restart the nodes just so that I can retrieve the log files?

Or is it possible to retrieve the EC2 disk without starting up the instance?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is. The instances are terminated and disks are not saved. Enabling log pushing to S3 is the best method to get the logs for EMR.